# @testing-library getByRole does not return elements hidden by CSS

Tags: css, testing-library

It might be the expected behavior, but I'd like to ensure and, if so, find an alternative way.

Suppose, there is a react element
`<span role="presentation" className="ag-hidden">`
where `ag-hidden` is defined in a stylesheet as
`.ag-hidden { visibility: hidden; }` or `display: none`.
The stylesheet is injected in the DOM.

- `screen.getAllByRole("presentation")` does not return the element.
- if the stylesheet is removed from the DOM, the element is found.
- a similar hidden element is found by test id, like this:
  `<span data-test="el" className="ag-hidden">`

I'd like to use the following, but it works strange:

```js
const selector = ".ag-hidden"l
const hiddenByRoleAndSelector = screen.queryByRole("presentation", {
  name: (_: string, el: Element) => {
    // the required element gets here, and it matches the selector
    console.log("n", el.matches(selector), el);
    // so we return true for it
    return el.matches(selector);
  }
});

// ...but eventually get null
```

So how should I test elements, which are hidden by styles? (not resorting all the time to test-ids or localizable label, text, etc.)

[Here is the codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-testing-library-yhydtg?file=/src/App.spec.tsx:1266-1590).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of RTL is it tests what your users see on the screen. But I get that can be frustrating sometimes when you need to test a very specific element.

You have an escape hatch in the form of the [underlying jest jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) selectors. You can use `querySelector` like you would in the browser to find a specific class, like the `ag-hidden` for example. Or you can use `data-test-id` as you already showed.

Comment: Yes, RTL is not a unit testing library, but rather something between integration and e2e. It's really odd and inconsistent behavior to return `null` from `queryByRole` while its filtering callback has resulted in `true`. At least, the callback shouldn't be called for the element then.

Comment: While it might be flakey, I was able to select my element using this approach: `el = screen.getByRole('button');  input = el.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];`

Answer (score 3):

queryByRole does include hidden properties if you query for it:

```js
  const hiddenDiv = screen.queryByRole('presentation', { hidden: true });
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: this still does not work with elements that are hidden visually, e.g. "sr-only" styling such as `height: 1px; width: 1px; overflow: hidden`

Comment: This does not work for hidden inputs. 
I think using `data-testid` attribute is the best solution since the user can't see hidden field